# How to return the value of a dynamic javascript object from an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have the following code which generates a success response:

```
<form method="post" action="/action/">
<script>
var = dynVal = "1";
</script>
<input type="submit">
</form>   
<script>
$("form").live("submit", function() { 
  $.ajax({  
    type: $(this).attr('method'),  
    url: $(this).attr('action'),  
    data: $(this).serialize(),  
    success: function(data) {  
     console.log('woohoo, this works! ');
     var newSummary = $(data).find("form");
     $("form").remove();
     $(".wrapper").prepend(newSummary);
    }  
  }); 
  return false;

});
</script>
```

Response:

```
<form method="post" action="/action/">
<script>
var = dynVal = "2";
</script>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Where the value of dynVal is incremented/updated once the form has been posted.

Within the response there is dynamic data stored within a custom data object that I am trying to reference without any success.

Do I need to better define the callback scope? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the current form? You can do `$form.replaceWith($(data).find('form'))`. You'd just need to keep a reference to the form. Also, `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Can you show an example what response data looks like?

Comment: I understand live is deprecated, but we are using an older framework

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but I'm not exactly sure that data returns as an html object and would be able to use find to find the form on the data like that. You would most likely need to assign the data to an HTML element that is hidden and then find the form within that THEN remove the form... I will submit a quick answer for this... sec..

Comment: @designmode ... I submitted an answer give me feedback if you don't understand or doesn't work. I would recommend updating your framework to be a more recent one, but I don't know why you are using an older one. If you can it would be the best thing to move forward so you can change `live` to `on` and make the script I wrote work 100% without question. Live did not always work when a new item was generated, but `on` does. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="/action/">
  // stuff... use a real html comment though (>.>
<input type="submit">
</form>   
<div id="someotherelement" style="display: none;"></div>
<script>
var = dynVal = "1";
$("form").live("submit", function() { 
   var _this = $(this);
  $.ajax({  
    type: _this.attr('method'),  
    url: _this.attr('action'),  
    data: _this.serialize(),  
    success: function(data) {  
     console.log('woohoo, this works! ');
      $('#someotherelement').html(data);
     var newSummary = $('#someotherelement').find("form");
     _this.remove();
     $(".wrapper").prepend(newSummary);

     $('#someotherelement').empty(); // or .html(' ')

     dynVal += 1; // this addresses your update variable option. Just make it a global scope and update it everytime there is a successful interaction. Or you can do a check if something occurs or you find a successful update, but updating global scope vs always replacing script is better. I don't even know if script executes the way you are trying to tbh. 
    }  
  }); 
  return false;

});
</script>
```

This should work for you... Use a different name for `#someotherelement` or don't. And then also you can set all the `$('#someotherelement')` to a variable and use that instead which would make this much better. I just wanted to make it stand out that you need to do it in multiple areas.

You may want to use something other than prepend or a different wrapper for the form so that you can just replace the exact location of the form just in case you have content below the form you don't suddenly change the location of the form. Just keep that in mind.. I don't think I missed anything..